# How to make an archive page in blogger

Tags: indexing, blogger, archive

I'm looking to make an archive page (like an index page) in blogger for topics like crafts and recipes. I want to have 145x145 px square pictures with text below. I've managed to do this, but I can't figure out how to make a table with a width of 600 px that automatically drops the full row to the next row. I don't want to be constantly adjusting the rows each time I add content (I want four across with the newest first).

Does anyone know how to make this a little easier and easier to keep updated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this belongs on another site, since it isn't a programming question. Maybe superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using ajax.

Wrap the part you want to display on your archive page in a container and name it with a class.

Then create the archive page.

Within your archive page, create empty containers with an id:

You want to remember your URL and then create a conditional Tag within your Code:

This is what I did for my tutorial overview, you might want to check it out:

http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/p/tutorials_14.html

So I did this for every category.

Basically I am loading post with the label blogger within the container with the ID Blogger. Ajax adds the HTML you tell it. I say to load the post-link but you would just replace the post link with your container class.

```
<!-- Tutorials -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;p/tutorials_14.html&quot;'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#Blogger").load("/search/label/Blogger?max-results=300 .post-link");
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</b:if>
```